# Getting (row count - 1) of CSV files

Tags: python, bash, csv

Mainly have 2 questions in respect to this topic:

1. I'm looking to get the row counts of a few CSV files. In Bash, I know I can do `wc -l < filename.csv`. How do I do this and subtract 1 from it (because of headers)?
2. For anyone familiar with CSV files and possible issues with grabbing raw line count, how plausible is it that a line is wrapped across multiple lines? I know that this is a very possible scenario, but want to say that this never happens. In the event of this being a possibility, would using Python's `csv` package be better to use? Does it read lines based on delimiters and other column wrappers?

Comment: Put the line count in a variable, and use `$((var - 1))` to subtract 1 from it.

Comment: CSV allows for fields to have newlines in them, they'll be wrapped in quotes when this happens. Whether it's plausible for a particular CSV depends on the kind of data it holds. A CSV library in a programming language will usually deal with this, it's difficult in plain `bash`.

Answer (score 2):

As Barmar points out, (1) it is quite possible for CSV files to have wrapped lines and (2) CSV programming libraries can handle this well.  As an example, here is a python program which uses python's CSV module to count the number of lines in `file.csv` minus 1:

```
python -c 'import csv; print( sum(1 for line in csv.reader(open("file.csv")))-1 )'
```

The `-c arg` option tells python to treat the `arg` string as a program to execute.  In this case, we make the `csv` module available with the "import" statement.  Then, we print out the number of lines minus one.  The construct `sum(1 for line in csv.reader(open("file.csv")))` counts the lines one at a time.

If your csv file has a non-typical format, you will need to set options.  This might be the delimiter or quoting character.  See [the documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html) for details.

#### Example

Consider this test file:

```
$ cat file.csv
First name,Last name,Address
John,Smith,"P O Box 1234
Somewhere, State"
Jane,Doe,"Unknown"
```

This file has two rows plus a header.  One of the rows is split over two lines.  Python's csv module correctly understands this:

```
$ python -c 'import csv; print( sum(1 for line in csv.reader(open("file.csv")))-1 )' 
2
```

#### gzipped files

To open gzip files in python, we use the `gzip` module:

```
$ python -c 'import csv, gzip; print( sum(1 for line in csv.reader(gzip.GzipFile("file.csv.gz")))-1 )' 
2
```

Comment: Ooh I like this. What's the c option in the command? And the files are originally `gz`  compressed. Would it be possible to pipe over uncompressed files and use them in the python command, all done in one line?

Comment: @simplycoding I updated the answer to handle gzip files.  Separately, the `-c` option tells python to treat the string that follows as its program.

Answer (score 1):

For getting the line count, just subtract 1 from the value returned by `wc` using an arithmetic expression

```
count=$(($(wc -l < filename.csv) - 1)
```

CSV format allows fields to contain newlines, by surrounding the field with quotes, e.g.

```
field1,field2,"field3 broken
across lines",field4
```

Dealing with this in a plain `bash` script would be difficult (indeed, any CSV processing that needs to handle quoted fields is tricky). If you need to deal with the full generality of CSV, you should probably use a programming language with a CSV library.

But if you know that your CSV files will never be like this, you can ignore it.

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative to subtracting one from the total row count, you can discard the first line from the file before

```
row_count=$( { read; wc -l; } < filename.csv )
```

(This is in no way better than simply using `$(($(wc -l < filename.csv) - 1))`; it's just a useful trick to know.)